# BIOS flash can load grub but not an OS

Tags: bios, bootloader, flashing

I have a Gigabyte motherboard with Award BIOS. After flashing the BIOS to the next revision, I noticed that GRUB 2 loads perfectly fine, but starting an OS (Windows 7, Arch Linux) fails to startup more than once? Specifically, Windows will begin by loading a portion of drivers and then immediately restart. Linux immediately restarts after the entry is selected from Grub. What is going on after flashing the BIOS that it is able to load a bootloader, but not an OS?

Comment: How does it fail? Does it crash, does it hang? Sit at a black screen? More details would be appreciated!

Comment: @Jeff F. It seems to crash and then restart. The timing differs depending on whether Windows is booted with safe mode, normal mode, recovery, etc.

Comment: So it starts loading into the OS, Can you bring up the advanced boot menu for Windows by tapping F8 after grub?

Comment: @Jeff F. Yes, the advanced menu appears. After selecting any of the options, a white bar says "Loading Windows Files" and then crashes restarting the machine.

Comment: Hmm check your Bios settings carefully like ACPI support ETC. It sounds like you lost/added hardware support different from when the OS was installed.

Comment: @Jeff F. Good point, I'll give it a shot.